# How to get current WindowsIdentity from Azure

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, active-directory

We're developing an internal site using MVC, Entity Framework and Azure. Employees will come and perform different work related actions but we want to authenticate through our on premise AD. We have an app service with a VNet configured to our on-premise AD. I can take a user's username and password and make the calls to verify them against the AD just fine. What I'm trying to do is automatically grab their WindowsIdentity and automatically look them up to reduce some of the steps the user has to make and automatically sign them in if possible. Otherwise I will re-direct them to the Login screen.

When I call the code

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

it returns "IIS APPPOOL\Test-WebApp" and not "DOMAIN\UserName" that I'm looking for.

I've tried adding the following to the web.config.

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
   <allow users="*"/>
 </authorization>
```

But this gives me a "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." error. I get the same error if I attempt to get this information from `UserPrincipal.Current` as well.

Can someone please help point me in the right direction on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please help point me in the right direction on this?

It seems that you using the Azure WebApp service, if it is that case, **unfortuntly, we can't use the Windows Authentication in azure WebApp service**.

Maybe Azure Web Sites Azure Actice Directy is the best option. [Sync from AD to Azure Actice Directy](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-sync-on-premises-active-directory-to-azure-active-directory-with-azure-ad-connect/) is also quite easy to setup. Then use [Azure Easy Authentication](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/azure-websites-easy-authentication-and-authorization-with-chris-gillum/) to do that.

If you still want to use the Windows Authentication, I recommand that you could use the [Azure VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/overview). You need to join the VM to your AD.

Comment: Thanks for the information Tom. The more I read, the more I'm finding confirmation on what you stated. At the moment we cannot use Azure AD and are too far along to change to a VM. This was just a "nice to have" feature we were trying to implement.